# Poco Process don't exit

Tags: c++, ubuntu, process, poco-libraries

When using Poco's `Process::launch(command,args)` I noticed that on a Linux machine the implementation process doesn't die.
When looking at the process it gets a waiting channel of `do_exit` and a zombie status (Ubuntu).
Somehow it doesn't go away.

Is this normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

you should get the process handle.

```
Poco::ProcessHandle handle = Process::launch(command,args)
```

then use handle to kill or wait

```
handle.wait; // wait untill process finshes job
Process.kill(handle); // kill process
```